# XML parsing: attributes instead of elements

Tags: c#, xml, linq, parsing, linq-to-xml

So I have this c# code that does a great job at parsing the following XML into an array:

```csharp
var doc = XDocument.Load(path).Root
                              .Elements()
                              .Select(y => y.Elements().ToDictionary(x => x.Name, x => x.Value))
                              .ToArray();
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<bbb>
    <a>
        <x>green</x>
        <y>4</y>
        <z>3</z>
    </a>
</bbb>
```

but I instead want to be able to write the XML like

```xml
<a x="green" y="4" z="3" />
```

How should I change the C# so that it ends up with the same result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
.Select(y => y.Attributes()
              .ToDictionary(x => x.Name, x => x.Value))
```